# "Assigned To" emails: how to control columns included?

Tags: 2007, column, email

We have an Issue Tracking list in a SharePoint 2007 instance which contains a column "Assigned To". The list has property "Send e-mail when ownership is assigned?" = Yes

We do not use columns "Category" and "Priority" and have hidden them. We also added a few hidden columns as helper columns for SharePoint Designer 2007 workflows (for example, manipulating text of the title and datetime fields).

SharePoint seems to include these hidden columns, however, within the emails generated when we add users to the "Assigned To" field.

How do I tell SharePoint to not include these hidden columns in emails generated automatically?

One idea: generate a workflow using SharePoint Designer 2007 to mimic this functionality...would like to think I can control this within SharePoint 2007 somehow, though?

Answer (score 1):

As you say in your question, sending the emails through SharePoint Designer would allow you to control which fields are included. Can you do this?

Comment: Yes...I think we ended up choosing this route. Sounds like this represents the only option.